# Kurento media server and android client socket connection stops working after 4-5 minutes

Tags: android, websocket, kurento

I am working on a Android VOIP call application, which uses **Kurento Media server 6.6.1**.
I am using **Nubomedia Android client** to communicate with Kurento media server.
 Currently I am able to initiate web socket connection with media server and **able to successfully communicate with server**.

**But this works for 4-5 minutes, after which at server end we are not receiving any message from the client.** Important point here is we are not getting socket disconnect event at both the end. I have ensured that android client is contentiously sending message to server (Heartbeat message , duration 1 minutes). But after 4-5 minutes server stops receiving message. (On android client I am able to see, client is sending message to server.)

It will be great if some one can help. Thanks in advance.